# Switching openvpn.exe in client mode to another ovpn file on the fly

Tags: vpn, openvpn

I want to run openvnp

```
openvnp.exe --config my_config.ovpn  --service my_service 0
```

and after an arbitrary period of time, I want to switch it to another ovpn file `my_config2.ovpn` on the fly without having to finish the process and run it again. The connection established by `my_config.ovpn` has to be finished, but the process `openvnp.exe` shouldn't not.

Is it possible? Or do I have to finish it to do that?

Answer (score 1):

OpenVPN does **not** support switching config files "on the fly".

Comment: However, you can run two `openvpn` instances at the same time and then use a firewall to block one or the other on demand.

Comment: If you clarify your question with specific details it may be possible to provide a more positive solution

Comment: I don't need only 2, I'll need to switch between tens or hundreds of ovpn files. Impossible?

Comment: You can run *many* openvpn configs at the same time and the priciple of blocking with a firewall would still stand. But I think you are trying to do something OpenVPN is simply not designed to do.

Comment: Another approach could be to use the `<connection> remote ip port proto </connection>` block approach (see the openvpn manual) but that will still require some form of network admin (ie. Firewall) to unblock/block destinations "on the fly".